# Why does year return 116 instead of 2016 in C?

Tags: c, date, time.h

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h>       

int main(void) {

    time_t rawtime = time(NULL);
    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("The time is: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", ptm->tm_hour, 
           ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
    printf("The date is: %02d:%02d:%04d\n.", ptm->tm_mday, ptm->tm_mon, ptm->tm_year);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, it returns the value of `tm_year` as 116 instead of 2016. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation? What does `tm_year` store?

Comment: @n.m. It has been declared in the library time.h like this: 

struct tm
{
  int tm_sec;
  int tm_min;
  int tm_hour;
  int tm_mday;
  int tm_mon;
  int tm_year;
  int tm_wday;
  int tm_yday;
  int tm_isdst;

Comment: Please read the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime)

Comment: sorry i was a little bit careless when asking this question @@ My bad

Comment: Yoy should read the documentation rather than the implementation. The implementation tells you that tm_year stores some integer. What next?

Answer (score 3):

The `tm_year` field is represented as years since 1900: https://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime

Comment: Sorry but I do not get what you said. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @A.Pearce - Please explain what part you do not understand

Comment: How can I be more specific than that? That field is simply defined as the number of years since 1900. Since the year is 2016 then 2016 - 1900 = 116.

Comment: Edit: sorry now I get what you mean

Answer (score 2):

As `tm_year` is the number of years since 1900, you need to add 1900 to this.

Source: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html

So you get:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h>  

int main(void) {

    time_t rawtime = time(NULL);
    struct tm *ptm = localtime(&rawtime);
    printf("The time is: %02d:%02d:%02d\n", ptm->tm_hour, 
           ptm->tm_min, ptm->tm_sec);
    printf("The date is: %02d:%02d:%04d\n.", ptm->tm_mday, ptm->tm_mon, ptm->tm_year+1900);
    return 0;
}
```